# Select query for relevant data while removing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID  Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Col_D   Col_E   Col_F   Col_G   Col_H
1   yyy     null    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
1   yyy     null    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    null
1   yyy     null    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0
1   yyy     null    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    null
1   yyy     null    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0
26  null    17,5    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    null
26  null    17,5    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
26  null    17,5    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0
26  null    17,5    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0
26  null    17,5    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
```

I want to remove duplicate ID's, but keep relevant data. So desired result here would be:

```
ID  Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Col_D   Col_E   Col_F   Col_G   Col_H
1   yyy     null    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
26  null    17,5    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
```

The code I tried was:

```
  SELECT ID, 
  MAX (ISNULL (Col_A, 0)) AS Col_A,
  MAX (ISNULL (Col_B, 0)) AS Col_B,
  MAX (ISNULL (Col_C, 0)) AS Col_C,
  MAX (ISNULL (Col_D, 0)) AS Col_D,
  MAX (ISNULL (Col_E, 0)) AS Col_E,
  MAX (ISNULL (Col_F, 0)) AS Col_F,
  MAX (ISNULL (Col_G, 0)) AS Col_G,
  MAX (ISNULL (Col_H, 0)) AS Col_H
  FROM TableA
  GROUP BY ID
  ORDER BY 1
```

Working on MSSQL 2008

Comment: I edited the title since you don't actually want to _remove_ duplicates from your table, you only want to select non duplicate records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
select max(col_a) as col_a,
       max(col_b) as col_b,
       . . .
from tablea
group by id
order by id;
```

The `isnull()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respons. Col_H gives me NULL in stead of the desired value 1. (for both ID's here)

Comment: Sorry about that, I was chasing a ghost. For some reason Col_H contains the string 'null' in stead of NULL in the sence of absence of data. Therefor the MAX did not work as expected. Your answer was correct. Thanks again!